# MYSQL - select TABLE A rows that are not in Table B except the rows are in TABLE C

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-select-db

TABLE A:

> dvdID.......dvdTitle
>
> d01..........Avenger
>
> d02..........Avenger
>
> d03..........Spiderman

TABLE B:

> rentID.......dvdID
>
> r01...........d01
>
> r02...........d02
>
> r03...........d03

TABLE C:

> returnID.......rentID
>
> t01...............r01

i want to select dvd that not in Table B (rented) except it in Table C (returned)
so the output should be like this:

OUTPUT:

> dvdID.......dvdTitle
>
> d01..........Avenger

could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT *
FROM A 
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.dvdID=A.dvdID))
   OR (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM C,B WHERE C.rentID=B.rentID and B.dvdID=A.dvdID))
```

here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50272/1)

Comment: nice, you're correct sir. maybe it's because you use SQLFiddle that really help alot, thanks anyway :)

Comment: anyway could you give some tips (maybe references like ebook) to help me learn mySQL?

Comment: Well, I learned SQL from my syllabus books long back (about 5 year back). You just look for SQL tutorials and by the practice you'l become master in it.

Comment: No tutorial can be compared with "Practice", only practice will make you more confident. Just try examples and go through with `joins, group by, order by, aggregate functions` those are basics of SQL which are commonly used in every DBMS.

Comment: As mentioned, using an outer join performs faster. I have updated the SQLFiddle to demonstrate how to do this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50272/19

Answer (score 3):

You can use existential quantifiers in your SQL conditions, represented by the `EXISTS` keyword:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (        -- No rental record
    SELECT *
    FROM TableB b
    WHERE b.dvdID=a.dvdID -- The record is for this DVD, and...
      AND NOT EXISTS (    -- ...there is no return record
          SELECT * FROM TableC c WHERE c.rentID=b.rentID
      )
)
```

The query reads almost like a poorly constructed English sentence, but it explains what is going on.

Comment: If you see the schema and sample dataset there is no direct relationship between tableA and tableC thus this will give no reultset

Comment: It would be faster to use OUTER JOINs rather than EXISTS

Comment: @StanislavL This may have been the case a decade ago, but it is no longer even close to the truth. All non-toy RDBMS engines have this figured out long time ago, so an `EXIST` query will be almost as fast as an equivalent query with a join.

Comment: No, Your subquery is executed for each row in TableA to compare with a.id. You can try to reproduce yourself.

Comment: Reproduce the case (create a dummy tables and fill them with some significant amount of rows and run your query and write one more query with JOINs). It does not depend on RDBMS.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight c.id and a.id? there is no a foreign key that connect c to a. could you be more spesific? maybe use fiddle demo

Comment: @StanislavL I have tried a correlated `EXISTS` a great deal of times, always with extremely satisfactory results. If I can convert my query to avoid a table scan, modern query optimizers are capable of doing it too. Ten..fifteen years ago the situation has been different.

Comment: well actually i have found the answer by Log1c.. your answer is like ~a & ~b and log1c's answer is like ~a | b. in theory both are diff but in this particular problem both answer can solved it. but anyway thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

From your sample data set it is clear that you need the dvds whose rent exists in TableC for this you can do so a simple `INNER` join ,last join from table3 will satisfy the rent exist condition for a dvd from table1

```
select t1.* FROM
Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 USING(dvdID)
JOIN Table3 USING(rentID)
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4579e/3)

Comment: it should be OUTER join and Table2.id is null to select dvd that not in Table B

Comment: +1 for replacing with LEFT JOIN but also should be WHERE Table2.id is null

Answer (score 1):

try this
Option 1

```
select * from A 
where dvdID not in (Select dvdID from B where rentID not in (select rentID from C))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TableA.dvdID, TableA.dvdTitle 
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.dvdID = TableB.dvdID
LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableC.rentID = TableB.rentID
WHERE TableB.rentID IS NULL
   OR (TableB.rentID IS NOT NULL
       AND TableC.returnID IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JOINS` instead of `EXISTS / NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM TableA a
    LEFT join TableB b
        on b.id=a.id
    LEFT Join TableC c 
        on c.id=a.id
WHERE
    b.id is null 
    OR (b.id is not null AND c.id is not null)
```